# Django get latest foreign count for group

Tags: django, orm, group-by

I am using django 1.8.4.
I would like to get the problem count for the latest test for each name.

The model

```
class MyTest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()

class Problem(models.Model)
    test = models.ForeignKey(MyTest, related_name='problems')
    description = models.charField()
```

Now, i want to get the problems count for latest test for each name.
For example if my table data is

```
name  date       problems count
foo   10.10.15    50
foo   10.09.15    30
bar   10.07.15    23
foo   10.03.15    54
bar   05.03.15    31
foo   10.01.15    97
```

Then i would like to get.

```
name  date       problems count
foo   10.10.15    50
bar   10.07.15    23
```

What i tried so far:

```
last_date = MyTest.objects.values('name').annotate(max_date=Max('date'))
```

This gives me the last date for each name.I then tried this:

```
last_test_pcount = MyTest.objects.values('name').annotate(max_date=Max('date'),pcount=Count('problems'))
```

This gives me the sum of all problems for each test and not only the count for the last test.

Answer (score 0):

try:

Get the latest test for each name:

```
tests = Mytest.objects.order_by('name','-date').distinct('name').values('id','name','date')
```

Add the problem count for each test:

```
for test in tests:
    test['pcount'] = Problem.objects.get(test_id=test['id']).count()
```

Sort the list of tests based on date

```
result = sorted(tests, key=lambda k: k['date'], reverse=True)
```